# Contents of sidewaystable do not appear

Tags: fontspec, babel, arabic, sidewaystable

For the shown MWE, upon using the `sidewaystable", the page appears blank, yet upon using ordinary table environment, all works fine. However, I need to use`sidewaystable` or landscape environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabu,multirow} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\begin{center}
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}c|} 
\rowcolor{white}
\toprule[1mm] 
\multicolumn{3}{?{1mm}c|}{\textbf{اللغة}} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cmidrule[1.25pt]{1-3} 
\rowcolor{white} 
العربية &
العبرانية &
وجه التشابة &
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{ملاحظات}} 
\\
\midrule[1.5pt]
مَلِك & ميلْخِ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مُلُوكْ & مَلاخيمْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
نَفْسي & نَفْشِيْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
سَبْعَة & شِبْعَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَقُومُ & ياقُومْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَرحَضُ & يِرْحَاصْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
ثَلاَثَةُ   & شَلوشَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مَلَك   & ماَلاَخْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَدُهُ  & ياَدو & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيْايَ & أوتِيْ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيَّاكَ    & أوتْخَ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
أثنْاَنِ    & شَنَايِمْ & المعنى & -\\
\hline
يحرق    & يسْروفْ   & الوزن & على وزن "يَفْعُلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
يغسل    & يَخَبْيسْ & الوزن & على وزن "يُفَعِلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
تَكَلَّمْتُ & دَبَّرْتِيْ   & الوزن & على وزن "فَعْلْتُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
أنْقَطَعَ   & نِخْرَاتْ & المعنى & النون هي الزائدة في انفعل لفظاً ومعنى\\
\hline
يُصَلِي & يِتْپَلَيلْ   & الوزن & تقريباً على وزن "يَتَفَعْلُ" فهو في الأصل ثلاثي (أي من ثلاثة حروف) مع إضافة حرف المضارعة وحرف التاء بالإضافة لتشديد عين الفعل\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Page1]
[image: Page2]

Answer (score 3):

If I simplify your example a bit the table appears but in the wrong place going up not down from the top of the page,

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{rotating}


\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{CCCC} 

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\caption{capppp}

xxx

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|p{5cm}|c|} 
aaa&bbb&ccc&dd&eee\\
1&2&3&4&5
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

So it seems that the newish bidi code in babel and the rotating package are not agreeing somewhere on which way is up.

This isn't really an answer, sorry but I wanted to post the full example, I'll ping Javier to ask if babel or rotating is at fault here.

A workaround might be to use rotatebox and some vspace to keep things visible:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 

\begin{table}

\vspace{-.6\textheight}
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{.7\textheight}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}c|} 
\rowcolor{white}
\toprule[1mm] 
\multicolumn{3}{?{1mm}c|}{\textbf{اللغة}} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cmidrule[1.25pt]{1-3} 
\rowcolor{white} 
العربية &
العبرانية &
وجه التشابة &
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{ملاحظات}} 
\\
\midrule[1.5pt]
مَلِك & ميلْخِ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مُلُوكْ & مَلاخيمْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
نَفْسي & نَفْشِيْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
سَبْعَة & شِبْعَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَقُومُ & ياقُومْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَرحَضُ & يِرْحَاصْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
ثَلاَثَةُ   & شَلوشَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مَلَك   & ماَلاَخْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَدُهُ  & ياَدو & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيْايَ & أوتِيْ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيَّاكَ    & أوتْخَ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
أثنْاَنِ    & شَنَايِمْ & المعنى & -\\
\hline
يحرق    & يسْروفْ   & الوزن & على وزن "يَفْعُلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
يغسل    & يَخَبْيسْ & الوزن & على وزن "يُفَعِلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
تَكَلَّمْتُ & دَبَّرْتِيْ   & الوزن & على وزن "فَعْلْتُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
أنْقَطَعَ   & نِخْرَاتْ & المعنى & النون هي الزائدة في انفعل لفظاً ومعنى\\
\hline
يُصَلِي & يِتْپَلَيلْ   & الوزن & تقريباً على وزن "يَتَفَعْلُ" فهو في الأصل ثلاثي (أي من ثلاثة حروف) مع إضافة حرف المضارعة وحرف التاء بالإضافة لتشديد عين الفعل\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{minipage}}

\vspace{.6\textheight}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you may also consider this question, where the same issue occurs in landscape environment, so if you may please also ask Javier regarding the landscape/pdflandscape package as well https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520471/table-does-not-appear-in-landscape-environment

Comment: @Silva I haven't done anything about this today (It's Christmas:-) It may be best if you raise the issue here https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/  I could do it but I can't read Arabic so testing or discussing  any examples is a bit tricky for me.

Comment: This is my first time on GitHUB, I would be grateful if you followup with me since I need this issue resolved ASAP. https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/42#issue-542399075

Comment: @ David, will this solution work with "Longtable" for multipage tables, also does it work if I need landscape page? since a fix was not found till now, so i may need to resort to your solution, although I was hoping for a fix!!

Comment: @Silva you could try it and let me know... The issue goes deeper than babel and isn't easy to get all parts of the stack to be fixed and be compatible, especially as the underlying right to left primitives are very different on luatex than they are in xetex and pdftex I raised an issue here https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/241 (but no fixes yet, sorry)

Comment: @ David, did not work if you may please see the follow question: up:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525536/mini-page-and-longtable

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527020/change-page-layout-mid-document-in-lualatex

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this unresolved issue, the workaround proposed by "Ulrike Fischer" as shown in [Change page layout mid-document in lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527020/change-page-layout-mid-document-in-lualatex/527031#527031)
can be used where it fully resolves this problem.