# Mini page and longtable

Tags: tables, minipage, landscape

I have been facing an issue in using sideways table for RTL documents, so a proposed solution was the use of minipage option. However, such option did work with single page tables only, yet with multi-page tables it caused an issue as shown in the figure below.
Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabu,multirow}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 

\begin{landscape}
\vspace{-.6\textheight}
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{.7\textheight}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}c?{0.50mm}c|c?{0.50mm}c?{0.50mm}c|c?{1mm}c|}
\caption{المصوتات الامامية}
\label{tab:المصوتات الامامية}\\
\toprule[1mm]
\multicolumn{5}{c?{1mm}}{\textbf{المصوت}} & \multicolumn{2}{c?{1mm}}{\textbf{مثال النطق}} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
\textbf{النوع} & \textbf{رقم المصوت طبقاً لمخطط دانيال چونز} & \textbf{الاسم} & \textbf{طريقة تكوين الصوت} & \textbf{الرمز طبقاً لمخطط دانيال جونز} &\textbf{انجليزية} & \textbf{عربية} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
        \endfirsthead

\toprule[1mm]
\multicolumn{5}{c?{0.5mm}}{\textbf{المصوت}} & \multicolumn{2}{c?{1mm}}{\textbf{مثال النطق}} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
\textbf{النوع} & \textbf{رقم المصوت طبقاً لمخطط دانيال چونز} & \textbf{الاسم} & \textbf{طريقة تكوين الصوت} & \textbf{الرمز طبقاً لمخطط دانيال جونز} &\textbf{انجليزية} & \textbf{عربية} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
        \endhead



\multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{يُتْبَع}}\\ 
        \bottomrule
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule[1mm]
        \endlastfoot

\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\ 
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\ 
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\ 
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\ 
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\ 
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\
\rowcolor{gray!25}       
wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\       
 wewewew
&
232323
&
wewewe
&
12121212
&
qwqwqwqw
&
121212 
&
qwqwqwqw
\\    
\end{longtable}
\end{minipage}}
\vspace{.6\textheight} 
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Minipage + longtable of course does not make any sense, minipage are one page only. But why the combination of landscape _and_ rotate box. Perhaps you should start all over and explain what the goal is

Comment: @daleif, trying to find a workaround for this issue https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/241 through applying the approach described below on longtable https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521796/contents-of-sidewaystable-do-not-appear/521799?noredirect=1#comment1328791_521799