# spanning multipage mini-page

Tags: minipage

For the shown MWE, as a partial solution for the issue emphasized in the posts below:

[Contents of sidewaystable do not appear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521796/contents-of-sidewaystable-do-not-appear/521799?noredirect=1#comment1328791_521799)

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/241

I am trying to make a multi-page mini-page which is used to display a longtable in a landscape environment for a right to left document.

However, I have 2 queries:

- How do I get the mini-page to span across multiple pages so as to properly display the longtable.
- I used Vspace to control vertical position/alignment of the table/mini-page, how do I control the horizontal position/alignment??

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{fancybox, graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu,multirow}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{longtable,ltablex,array} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}



\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}

\vspace{1.05\textheight}
\rotatebox{0}{
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{longtable}{?{1mm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}c?{0.50mm}c|c?{0.50mm}c?{0.50mm}c|c?{1mm}c|}
\caption{المصوتات الامامية}
\label{tab:المصوتات الامامية}\\
\toprule[1mm]
\multicolumn{5}{c?{1mm}}{\textbf{المصوت}} & \multicolumn{2}{c?{1mm}}{\textbf{مثال النطق}} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
\textbf{النوع} & \textbf{رقم المصوت طبقاً لمخطط دانيال چونز} & \textbf{الاسم} & \textbf{طريقة تكوين الصوت} & \textbf{الرمز طبقاً لمخطط دانيال جونز} &\textbf{انجليزية} & \textbf{عربية} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
        \endfirsthead

\toprule[1mm]
\multicolumn{5}{c?{0.5mm}}{\textbf{المصوت}} & \multicolumn{2}{c?{1mm}}{\textbf{مثال النطق}} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
\textbf{النوع} & \textbf{رقم المصوت طبقاً لمخطط دانيال چونز} & \textbf{الاسم} & \textbf{طريقة تكوين الصوت} & \textbf{الرمز طبقاً لمخطط دانيال جونز} &\textbf{انجليزية} & \textbf{عربية} \\
\midrule[1.5pt]
        \endhead



\multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{يُتْبَع}}\\ 
        \bottomrule
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule[1mm]
        \endlastfoot

\rowcolor{gray!25}       
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\       
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\
ظهر
&
ذهب
&
فرح
&
كمر
&
رقم
&
فهم
&
جد
\\     
\end{longtable}
\end{minipage}
}
%\vspace{-.6\textheight}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Minipages cannot span more than one page.  One can use longtable in landscape (see rotating or pdflscape), although I have never tried right-tio-left text that way.

Comment: What you say is correct but not for right to left documents, please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521796/contents-of-sidewaystable-do-not-appear/521799?noredirect=1#comment1328791_521799

Comment: I tried removing everything except the longtable, and it still crashed.  Until you can get longtable to work, there is no point in messing with minipages or landscape.