# Change page layout mid-document in lualatex

Tags: landscape, layout

Due to certain technical unresolved issues emphasized in the posts below I am unable to use neither landscape nor pdfrotate nor minipage options to display content in landscape layout.

[Contents of sidewaystable do not appear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521796/contents-of-sidewaystable-do-not-appear/521799?noredirect=1#comment1328791_521799)

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/241

[spanning multipage mini-page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526368/spanning-multipage-mini-page?noredirect=1#comment1331494_526368)

Accordingly as a workaround, I tought about changing the page layout/dimension mid-document to landscape by using the commands "\newgeometry" and "\restoregeometry", upon compilation, no errors occur but also the document remains the same as if such commands are not used at all.

Here is a MWE (I am using lualatex + Babel):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tabu,multirow} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{?}[1]{!{\vrule width #1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 
\newgeometry{a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm,landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} 
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{?{1mm}c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}?{1mm}c|} 
\rowcolor{white}
\toprule[1mm] 
\multicolumn{3}{?{1mm}c|}{\textbf{اللغة}} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cmidrule[1.25pt]{1-3} 
\rowcolor{white} 
العربية &
العبرانية &
وجه التشابة &
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{ملاحظات}} 
\\
\midrule[1.5pt]
مَلِك & ميلْخِ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مُلُوكْ & مَلاخيمْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
نَفْسي & نَفْشِيْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
سَبْعَة & شِبْعَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَقُومُ & ياقُومْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَرحَضُ & يِرْحَاصْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
ثَلاَثَةُ   & شَلوشَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مَلَك   & ماَلاَخْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَدُهُ  & ياَدو & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيْايَ & أوتِيْ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيَّاكَ    & أوتْخَ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
أثنْاَنِ    & شَنَايِمْ & المعنى & -\\
\hline
يحرق    & يسْروفْ   & الوزن & على وزن "يَفْعُلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
يغسل    & يَخَبْيسْ & الوزن & على وزن "يُفَعِلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
تَكَلَّمْتُ & دَبَّرْتِيْ   & الوزن & على وزن "فَعْلْتُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
أنْقَطَعَ   & نِخْرَاتْ & المعنى & النون هي الزائدة في انفعل لفظاً ومعنى\\
\hline
يُصَلِي & يِتْپَلَيلْ   & الوزن & تقريباً على وزن "يَتَفَعْلُ" فهو في الأصل ثلاثي (أي من ثلاثة حروف) مع إضافة حرف المضارعة وحرف التاء بالإضافة لتشديد عين الفعل\\
\bottomrule[1mm] 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{table}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

geometry disables the options to change the paper size and orientation in \newgeometry - you can find warnings in the log.

You can try to trick it like the following. I simplified the tabular and removed the broken as I didn't want to have to correct the errors here.

### Edit

and as mentioned in a follow-up question ([Resolving landscape table bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575295/resolving-landscape-table-bug)) you also need to reset the landscape boolean when restoring from a landscape setting.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{%
  \ifGm@newgm
   %\Gm@warning{`#1': not available in `\string\newgeometry'; skipped}%
   \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi}%
\makeatother  
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
%
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير}

\newgeometry{landscape,margin=2.5cm}
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{llll}

مَلِك & ميلْخِ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مُلُوكْ & مَلاخيمْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
نَفْسي & نَفْشِيْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
سَبْعَة & شِبْعَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَقُومُ & ياقُومْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَرحَضُ & يِرْحَاصْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
ثَلاَثَةُ   & شَلوشَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مَلَك   & ماَلاَخْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَدُهُ  & ياَدو & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيْايَ & أوتِيْ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيَّاكَ    & أوتْخَ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
أثنْاَنِ    & شَنَايِمْ & المعنى & -\\
\hline
يحرق    & يسْروفْ   & الوزن & على وزن "يَفْعُلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
يغسل    & يَخَبْيسْ & الوزن & على وزن "يُفَعِلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
تَكَلَّمْتُ & دَبَّرْتِيْ   & الوزن & على وزن "فَعْلْتُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
أنْقَطَعَ   & نِخْرَاتْ & المعنى & النون هي الزائدة في انفعل لفظاً ومعنى\\
\hline
يُصَلِي & يِتْپَلَيلْ   & الوزن & تقريباً على وزن "يَتَفَعْلُ" فهو في الأصل ثلاثي (أي من ثلاثة حروف) مع إضافة حرف المضارعة وحرف التاء بالإضافة لتشديد عين الفعل\\
\bottomrule[1mm]
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\makeatletter \Gm@landscapefalse\makeatother %new
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a similar hack to change paper size mid-docment from A4 to A3?

Comment: @Silva did you try it?

Comment: I did, it works, sorry I failed to notice extra page size. THX

Comment: Upon trying to repeat the above command/macro within the same document, it does not work. It works only once within the same document, only usable for the first use. I posted this issue here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575295/resolving-landscape-table-bug if you can please check it out.