# Resolving landscape table bug

Tags: landscape, arabic

Regarding the solution proposed in this post

[Change page layout mid-document in lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527020/change-page-layout-mid-document-in-lualatex)

Which resolves the issue regarding displaying landscape contents in RTL documents.
This solution works only upon using it for the first time in a document, however, upon trying to repeat it in the same dosument, the paper remains in portrait mode and does not rotate. So this macro can only be used once in a document. I cannot figure out how to modify it so as to use it repeatedly whenever it is required.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{%
  \ifGm@newgm
   %\Gm@warning{`#1': not available in `\string\newgeometry'; skipped}%
   \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi}%
\makeatother  
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
%
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\chapter{شكر وتقدير}

\newgeometry{landscape,margin=2.5cm}
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{llll}

مَلِك & ميلْخِ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مُلُوكْ & مَلاخيمْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
نَفْسي & نَفْشِيْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
سَبْعَة & شِبْعَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَقُومُ & ياقُومْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَرحَضُ & يِرْحَاصْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
ثَلاَثَةُ   & شَلوشَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مَلَك   & ماَلاَخْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَدُهُ  & ياَدو & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيْايَ & أوتِيْ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيَّاكَ    & أوتْخَ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
أثنْاَنِ    & شَنَايِمْ & المعنى & -\\
\hline
يحرق    & يسْروفْ   & الوزن & على وزن "يَفْعُلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
يغسل    & يَخَبْيسْ & الوزن & على وزن "يُفَعِلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
تَكَلَّمْتُ & دَبَّرْتِيْ   & الوزن & على وزن "فَعْلْتُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
أنْقَطَعَ   & نِخْرَاتْ & المعنى & النون هي الزائدة في انفعل لفظاً ومعنى\\
\hline
يُصَلِي & يِتْپَلَيلْ   & الوزن & تقريباً على وزن "يَتَفَعْلُ" فهو في الأصل ثلاثي (أي من ثلاثة حروف) مع إضافة حرف المضارعة وحرف التاء بالإضافة لتشديد عين الفعل\\
\bottomrule[1mm]
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight
\lipsum



\newgeometry{landscape,margin=2.5cm}
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\caption{أمثلة لبعض الكلمات المتشابهة باللغات الناقلة}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{llll}

مَلِك & ميلْخِ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مُلُوكْ & مَلاخيمْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
نَفْسي & نَفْشِيْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
سَبْعَة & شِبْعَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَقُومُ & ياقُومْ   & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَرحَضُ & يِرْحَاصْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
ثَلاَثَةُ   & شَلوشَاهْ & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
مَلَك   & ماَلاَخْ  & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
يَدُهُ  & ياَدو & الحروف والمعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيْايَ & أوتِيْ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
إِيَّاكَ    & أوتْخَ    & المعنى & -\\
\hline
أثنْاَنِ    & شَنَايِمْ & المعنى & -\\
\hline
يحرق    & يسْروفْ   & الوزن & على وزن "يَفْعُلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
يغسل    & يَخَبْيسْ & الوزن & على وزن "يُفَعِلُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
تَكَلَّمْتُ & دَبَّرْتِيْ   & الوزن & على وزن "فَعْلْتُ" مع فرق بسيط\\
\hline
أنْقَطَعَ   & نِخْرَاتْ & المعنى & النون هي الزائدة في انفعل لفظاً ومعنى\\
\hline
يُصَلِي & يِتْپَلَيلْ   & الوزن & تقريباً على وزن "يَتَفَعْلُ" فهو في الأصل ثلاثي (أي من ثلاثة حروف) مع إضافة حرف المضارعة وحرف التاء بالإضافة لتشديد عين الفعل\\
\bottomrule[1mm]
\end{tabular}
\label{tab}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hm. if you set `\newgeometry{portrait,margin=2.5cm}` for the second table it works. Somewhere a boolean must be switched again.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, so, in this case, upon repition I have for each time I repeat the change in orientation to set \newgeometry{portrait,margin=2.5cm}? Also do you mean \newgeometry{portrait,margin=2.5cm} or \newgeometry{landscape,margin=2.5cm}?

Comment: sorry I don't have the time to look now which boolean needs to be switched here.

Comment: Insert `\restoregeometry` when you like to go from `\newgeomery` settings to default settings.

Comment: @Zarko, already \restoregeometry is used when you resotre your default settings as shown in the MWE, so can you emphasize more?

Comment: Yes, you have, but after (it) them) you have spurious code fragment `\pagewidth  = \paperwidth
\pageheight = \paperheight`. Try to remove them and than see, if compilation work and result is as desire. Unfortunately, I can't test your document since I haven't packages needed for its compilation not any experiences with them.

Comment: @Zarko, nope, your suggestion did not work, if I removed the geometry is not restored

Comment: Alternating between \newgeometry{portrait,margin=2.5cm} and \newgeometry{landscape,margin=2.5cm} is working, however, upon using the subfile package the arrangement differ since if I am compiling a single file, I only have to maintain the alternating sequence only within the compiled file. However, for multiple files compiled as a single file through the "Subfile package", the sequence of alternating between "Portrait" and "Landscape" has to be maintained across all files which is a bit confusing. Anyway, it is still acheivable, however it would be nice if anyone had any suggestions.

Comment: Still, no suggestions?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, It would be nice if this boolean switch issue is resolved as I am preparing a huge mutlifile document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, did you find anything with regard to this Bug?? I would be truly nice if it can be resolved since I am using this option quite a lot

Comment: How do we modify this code for use with titleps package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reset the geometry you must also tell geometry that the paper is no longer landscape

```
....
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\makeatletter \Gm@landscapefalse\makeatother %new
....
```