# Changing page size mid-document

Tags: page-breaking

Changing page size mid-document should be a basic, easy to use feature but it isn't.

I am developing upon the answer given at [Change paper size in mid-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Normal page
\eject \pdfpagewidth=3in \pdfpageheight=5in
Tall page
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=18in \pdfpageheight=3in
Wide page
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
    A & B\\
    c & D
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

There are a lot of problems:

1. modifying `\pdfpagewidth` does not modify `\paperwidth` which is commonly used to modify image size
2. The page number is shown only on the first page. How to show it on other pages and place it in the centre of the bottom of the page.
3. Why is "Tall page" shown at the bottom of the page?
4. Where is `example-image-a`?
5. Where is the table?
6. Where is the text placed by `\lipsum`?
7. `example-image-b` has been centred, but in the output it is in the left side of the page.

Comment: Each time the paper size changes, all the page geometry dimensions need an update.  You don't see page numbers and image`example-image-a` because they are typeset outside the page. Are there specific reasons you cannot use `typearea` package?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, I am not familiar with the `typearea` package. Does it provide an acceptable solution?

Comment: TeX can generally be considered some form of programming of a document, which inherently suggests that it imposes consistency of the structure. Changing page dimensions mid-document goes counter to that, even though WYSIWYG editors like Word make it possible. You'll have to manually inform TeX how to change the text width across the page break as well, since it naturally assumes the structure will remain consistent. What is the main intent behind the change?

Comment: Yes, there's a [`typearea` example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21431) under the question you mentioned.

Comment: If you do need to change the page size (which is very rare and contrary to your first line one of the trikiest thing sto do in a typesetting system with an asynchronous page breaker)  why not use the provided `\newgeometry` command since you are loading the `geometry` package that defines it. If you use tex primitive settings mid document without re-calculating all the latex structures built on them then things will break.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried the `\newgeometry` command but I encountered a problem which I have described in another question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622303/change-page-size-mid-document-with-newgeometry

Comment: @DavidCarlisle one need to trick newgeometry to accept a page size change, see e.g. the question and answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575295/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes I was just looking at the package now, I wonder if we should change that...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think changing also the page size should be possible too, that is a quite natural wish if documents are used only on screen, but as the landscape boolean shows one should be a bit careful and check if there are other side effect.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes a start at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622310/1090

Comment: @Viesturs do you want to close this in favour of the newgeometry question?  Since you are using that package I think you should use a compatible version even if \newgeopmetry doesn't handle this as well as I'd expected

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried your `\newgeometry` solution in the real document. The first impression is rather agreeable. Maybe somebody will answer this question explaining the limitations of `\eject` and  will point to better solutions.

Comment: @Werner, the main intention is to show large tables which do not fit into a page even when using `\tiny` font size.