# Change page size mid-document with \newgeometry

Tags: page-breaking

I am studying the example in https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12244

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[driver=pdftex]{geometry}
%\usepackage[driver=pdftex, paperwidth=10in]{geometry}                                                                                                                           

\begin{document}
This is a standard page.
\newpage
\newgeometry{paperwidth=17in,paperheight=11in}
This is a big landscape page.
\restoregeometry
\newpage
Back to a standard page
\end{document}
```

Looks like a nice solution, however during the compilation there is a problem:

```
Package geometry Warning: `paperwidth': not available in `\newgeometry'; skippe
d.
Package geometry Warning: `paperheight': not available in `\newgeometry'; skipp
ed.
```

Why this example does not work?

Interestingly, `paperwidth=10in` works if the line:

```
%\usepackage[driver=pdftex, paperwidth=10in]{geometry}
```

is uncommented.

Comment: the very first paragraph of the `geometry` package documentation `texdoc geometry` explicitly says the paper size options are not applicable here: `\newgeometry is almost similar to \geometry except that \newgeometry disables all the options speciﬁed in the preamble and skips the papersize-related options:` the package does list all th eavailable options which almost certainly will produce the effect you need, but I am not sure what that is from your description.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried the options `layoutwidth`, `layoutheight` but they do not change anything or I don't know how to use them. Could you please provide your answer to my `\newgeometry` question?

Comment: if you just want a landscape page of the smae physical size it would be simpler to use the lscape package and a `landscape` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to give `\newgeometry` a bit more help than I expected, but this appears to work

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
This is a standard page.


\clearpage
\edef\hmm{\pdfpagewidth=\the\pdfpagewidth \pdfpageheight=\the\pdfpageheight\relax}
\pdfpagewidth=17in
\pdfpageheight=11in
\newgeometry{top=1in,left=1in,textwidth=15in,textheight=9in}

This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. 
This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. 
This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. 
This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. 
This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. 
This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. 
This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page.

\vspace*{\fill}

This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. 
This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. This is a big landscape page. 
 
\restoregeometry
\hmm

Back to a standard page
\end{document}
```

Comment: but the textbody is not right. Try \lipsum on the page.

Comment: I blame @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer better?

Comment: Yes, but this naturally means that you have to do the calculation from geometry yourself. That's why I suggested to redefine `\ifGm@preamble` instead (and to reset the landscape bool if needed).

Comment: In the question \newpage was used, what are the advantages that \clearpage has over this?

Comment: you want to use `\clearpage` otherwise a normal width  figure may float into the area with a different page size and it won't be possible to place it in any sensible way.