# Set a fixed width for footer/header with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry, textwidth

I'm using the *geometry* package for settings like textwidth and margins. *fancyhdr* uses the initial text geometry setting. Through my document I also change the geometry of the text layout (i.e. not the page size/orientation) multiple times using `\newgeometry{}` (because my text is set relative to different background images in the document).

(If I change the geometry midways in the document, [There is a hack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598223/help-with-fancyhdr-on-custom-page-sizes/598241) so *fancyhdr* picks up and adapts to the new textwidth).

How can I set up the footer and header width for *fancyhdr* so that it is independent of the text geometry and never changes? So it keeps the width and never adapts to the geometry of the text. My specific case is that I want the width of the footer to fill up (almost) the whole page width and keep it so on every page where this page style applies.

Here is a small example that shows that the footer/header width is set from the original geometry and never changes (however, on each page it aligns to where the text begins):

```latex
\documentclass[8pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape,left=12.cm,right=12.cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% setup fancyhdr style "fancy"

\pagestyle{fancy}

% clear all
\fancyhf{} 

% header content
\fancyhf[HL]{Left eye}
\fancyhf[HC]{Nose}
\fancyhf[HR]{Right eye}

% footer content
\fancyhf[FL]{Left foot}
\fancyhf[FC]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[FR]{Right foot}

% show header and footer lines
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% TODO: here I would like some command/setting that sets up the header and 
%       footer width and keeps it through the whole document (unless changed), 
%       like \fancywidth{0.9\pagewidth} or \fancyfill{marginL}{marginR}. 
%
%       even better, this constant width setting should be possible to define 
%       for every \fancypagestyle (and if not defined, use the current behaviour).
%       this way we could switch easily between different setups.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section*{geometry}
\kant[1-4]
\newpage

\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm}
\section*{newgeometry\{left=1cm,right=1cm\}}
\kant[5-9]
\newpage

\newgeometry{left=20cm,right=11cm}
\section*{newgeometry\{left=20cm,right=11cm\}}
\kant[10-12]
\newpage

\restoregeometry
\section*{restoregeometry}
\kant[14-17]
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: A different approach is to set up an initial, fixed geometry that gives correct header/footer width, and then use minipages on every page to set my desired text geometry. But minipages creates other problems like footnotes.

Comment: What about using `changepage` and `adjustwidth`? Then you can alter the width of the text block without changing the actual layout. Otherwise, you are going to need to calculate appropriate offsets for the header/footer to compensate.

Comment: Off-topic: `8pt` is not a valid option. You are getting `10pt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, headers and footers are connected to the `\textwidth` (this is standard typographical practice). So you must now fool `fancyhdr` to compensate for your changes in the margins and `\textwidth`.

If you look at figure 1 in the `fancyhdr` documentation, you will see that the distance from the left edge of the paper to the left edge of the text is `1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin` So to get the header/footer on a fixed space from the left edge of the paper (say `1cm`), we have to shift the header by `-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin+1cm`

In order to keep a fixed width for the header/footer we should not use `\fancy..offset`, but rather set `\headwidth` to our desired value. In the example below I set it to `\paperwidth-2cm`, so that we get a margin of `1cm` at both ends, for the header and the footer, independent of the margins of the text. At least that is how I interpret you wishes.

```
\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm}

\fancyhfinit{%
  \hspace{\dimexpr-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin+1cm}%
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the complete document.

```
\documentclass[8pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape,left=12.cm,right=12.cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% setup fancyhdr style "fancy"

\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm}
\newlength{\fancyLM}
\fancyhfinit{%
  \hspace{\dimexpr-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin+1cm}%
}

% clear all
\fancyhf{} 

% header content
\fancyhf[HL]{Left eye}
\fancyhf[HC]{Nose}
\fancyhf[HR]{Right eye}

% footer content
\fancyhf[FL]{Left foot}
\fancyhf[FC]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[FR]{Right foot}

% show header and footer lines
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% TODO: here I would like some command/setting that sets up the header and 
%       footer width and keeps it through the whole document (unless changed), 
%       like \fancywidth{0.9\pagewidth} or \fancyfill{marginL}{marginR}. 
%
%       even better, this constant width setting should be possible to define 
%       for every \fancypagestyle (and if not defined, use the current behaviour).
%       this way we could switch easily between different setups.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\section*{geometry}
\kant[1-4]
\newpage

\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm}
\section*{newgeometry\{left=1cm,right=1cm\}}
\kant[5-9]
\newpage

\newgeometry{left=20cm,right=11cm}
\section*{newgeometry\{left=20cm,right=11cm\}}
\kant[10-12]
\newpage

\restoregeometry
\section*{restoregeometry}
\kant[14-17]
\newpage

\end{document}
```

By the way, there are other ways of putting text/images at a fixed place on the page, without using `fancyhdr`, like the `eso-pic` packages, or the LateX hooks for `shipout`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need :) A simple and good solution. It's also easy to wrap it into a custom command `\newcommand{\fancyfill}[1]{ ... }` with the argument defining the margins.

Comment: Worth to mention is that `\reversemarginpar` creates problem with this solution. I couldn't get things working in my real document, and I later found this inference. I just removed that setting because it was not relevant in my document.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. Probably in that case the marginpar width must also be taken into account, and maybe there is something with odd/even pages too. I will have a look and try to get it as complete as possible.